# Raspberry Pi as a Hi-Fi component

Tags: audio, pi-zero, electronics

After reading the [following post](https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2017/debian/raspberry-pi-as-a-hi-fi-component/), I was wondering if I could achieve something similar with my own setup. I do own an old [Technics SL505](https://www.hifiengine.com/images/model/technics_sc-ch505_component_audio_system.jpg). However the nasty part of this setup is that each components are connected to each other using some kind of specific Technics ribbon cable:

[image: Technics Ribbon Cable]

Opening the RS-CH404 cassette player component, I was able to see the labels:

[image: Inside RS CH404 cassette player]

However those do not make much sense to me. Could anyone confirm I should be able to plug my RPi Zero using this connection cables ?

Ideally I would power up the RPi Zero directly from it as well as connect the audio out to it.

---

Update, searching for the manual online, I was able to find a page where to [Download Technics SL-CH505 Service Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/download/925284/Technics-Sl-Ch505.html).

The schematic is given page 14:

[image: Technics Ribbon Cable Schematic]